# Assign a default value to a variable and change into database

Tags: c#, sql, oop

I have a method

```
getlisting(string url,int ID)
```

I am passing this parameter ID to another function in another class

```
 Controller __cc = new Controller();
                int Status = 1;
                __cc.UpdatePaging(ID, Status);
```

I am passing this to update function and want to assign a default value of 0 to ID and 1 to status and then return it and make changes in the database,

```
 public void UpdatePaging(int ID,int Status)
        {

               if (ID != null)
               {
                    ID = 0;
               }
               else 
               {
                    ID = 0;
               }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Paging SET Status='1' WHERE ID = @ID", obj.openConnection());
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
```

but I can't do it. Is there something wrong with my code? or tell me how to assign a 0 value to int and update it in Database, whenever I get any value from `getlisting` method it should be assigned zero and update in DB.

Comment: Well, to start an _int_ is never null. If you want to have a [nullable int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) then you should use the _int?_ However it is not clear what are your intentions, do you want to update a record with ID=0 ? It seems that whatever value is passed for ID you want to set it to zero

Comment: int is by default 0 if no value assigned

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - your comment makes no sense ID is passed to the function and the function does not declare a default.

Comment: Duplicate of [Assign a value through any condition to a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811561/assign-a-value-through-any-condition-to-a-parameter). Please do not re-post you questions. You asked the same thing some hours ago.

Comment: i said `int` has default value of 0 if no value assigned @Hogan

Comment: i just want every coming int in getlisting to be updated in update method and assign a zero value so my data table won't select that value again

Comment: and no one gave solution @khlr

Comment: @ShahRukh you want status to be assigned 0 based on the ID?

Comment: I think you need to show us the code for getlisting since it is not clear to me what to update.  It is also clear you don't really understand how your data model works.

Comment: i want to assign status value 1 and 0 to ID and then update in my cmd to database @hogan

Comment: @ShahRukh then why use a parameter --- `UPDATE Paging SET Status='1' WHERE ID = 0` would work fine. -- but that can't actually be what you mean -- you don't want to set 0 to ID -- ID (in every data model I have ever seen uniquely identifies the row.

Comment: i have 67 URLS in my DB and selecting them through data table and all has ID > 1 so what i want to do is which ever link comes in getlisting method its parameter ID should be assigned zero and update to database, because at the same time other records are also being inserted in that DB, so i want to give 0 to records which are processed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110022/discussion-between-shah-rukh-and-hogan).

Comment: _UPDATE Paging SET Status='1', ID=0 WHERE ID = @ID_ and of course do not mess with the ID value passed to the UpdatePaging method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on chat you want this:

```
public void UpdatePaging(int ID,int Status)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Paging SET Status='1' WHERE ID = @ID", obj.openConnection());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

this will set the status to 1 based on the id that is sent to the function

Note your code says `SET Status='1'` you might mean `SET Status=1`

You could also make your code more generic like this:

```
public void UpdatePaging(int ID,int Status=1)
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Paging SET Status=@Status WHERE ID = @ID", obj.openConnection());
  cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Status;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Status is working fine i get it 1 now, and what i should i do with ID??

Comment: Take it out to lunch